# Should we include a disclaimer for people to include their definitions in questions?

Tags: feature-request

This has been bugging me lately. A very large amount of questions ask for proofs of certain facts which are 100% definition dependent.

Since we've made a huge progress with homework as to include some of what many people agree is a good homework policy, would it be sensible to include a

**Don't forget to include the definitions you're using if they are relevant to your question! As a an example, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493936/how-do-i-prove-that-ex-sum-i-geq-0-xi-i), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493920/how-would-i-go-about-showing-cosx-frac-pi2-sinx) [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498598/prove-e-lnx-x), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480861/partial-a-is-a-closed-set/480870#comment1035604_480861). And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514878/show-that-cos-pi-1).**

disclaimer?

Comment: Yes! Explain all notation you are using.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo ?

Comment: I agree with you, Peter. The disclaimer should ask people to "explain all ..."

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Heh. For a moment I thought you were being sarcastic.

Comment: Ideally, yes. I've seen so many questions, where the asker apparently believes that the definition/notation in their textbook is in universal use. Early in their careers people simply have not been exposed to enough many texts - well we all started from a single book! I think we could include a warning in the FAQ about this, but expecting people to comply and understand the reason for this is asking a lot.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That did cross my mind. Maybe one can see it as a chance for people to learn new things at the same moment. Someone might be kind enough to make an article. "Why do definitions matter?". I don't think I am the appropriate candidate! =P

Comment: @Jyrki: We can always include a clause allowing us to legally fire them in case they disregard this point. And of course, when I say fire, I mean out of a cannon. Into the sun.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Although Jules Verne considered such a means of travel, it has serious practical difficulties. Even if, as in this case, fatally high acceleration is not a problem, atmospheric drag and gravity are huge ones. The muzzle velocity of the cannon will have to be substantially *greater* than escape velocity. Even if you could pack that much punch into a cannon, I doubt very much that the craft would remain intact for long.

Comment: This question needs more upvotes. As [Jyrki Lahtonen](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) [pointed out](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10973/should-we-include-a-disclaimer-for-people-to-include-their-definitions-in-questi#comment41454_10973), `the asker apparently believes that the definition/notation in their textbook is in universal use`.

Comment: maybe also  question to include booktitles where appropriate

Comment: @dfeuer: You obviously missed the clear reference to Futurama; more specifically the very first episode.

Comment: Also: We should not be shy about putting questions on hold until definitions (etc.) are inserted by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I use to be a little bit lazy with including definitions/theorems from my book. I know use a method that makes pasting definitions realy easily done using adobe reader and http://snag.gy/:

1. Adobe Reader -> Edit -> Take a snapshot
2. Select the text you want to copy
3. Crt-V at http://snag.gy/

And the rest should speak for itself. For example:

[image: http://snag.gy/sPB71.jpg]